# TFS - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Needed to delete a branch in one team project so ran this command: `tf destroy $/MyProject/Main/Bin /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/myproject`

The command completed but now when I open visual studio I get multiple errors with same message, saying

> An item with the same key has already been added

Most solutions on SO recommend emptying out the cache folder under AppData which I've already done - does not help in my case.
Now I cannot open **any** team project in my collection. All because I deleted one branch in one team project from command line!

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Team Foundation Server 2015 Version 14.102.25423.0 (Tfs2015.Update3)

[image: error 1]
[image: error 2]
[image: error 3]

**And this operation never completes, stuck at "Working..."**

[image: waiting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below ways:

1. Make sure any instances of Visual Studio are not running, then delete
   all the caches files:

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation[version]\Cache
   C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Team Explore
2. Try to reset all environment settings:

   Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings
3. Add a new workspace and map the sources to another location

   Go to "File"-> "Source Control" -> "Advanced" -> "Workspaces..."
4. Try to run Visual Studio with another valid user by this command: (Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE)

   runas /netonly /user: devenv.exe

Comment: nothing worked...nothing! even upgrading VS2015 to 2017. except....remapping the workspace. thanks so much!!

Comment: Thanks Andy-MSFT, i had a similar issue and the deletion of C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation[version]\Cache  fixed it.